# How can I track how many calories I'm losing in a day?

Tags: workout, calories, metabolism

I want to know how many calories I lose per day. Tracking amount of calorie I take wouldn't be a problem if I read labels in food.

But how do I know how much calorie I'm loosing?

On the weekdays,
I ride bicycle 10 mins for home to station for train. 
Then 20 mins from the train station to work.

same when I come back, 20 mins then 10.

So, it is like 1 hr of bicycle ride per day. But not continuous.
I also workout but number of days are not fixed yet. It is somewhere in the range from 2-4.

My BF is around 17% and I want to reach at the level of 10% by the end of June.

Any tips of hints.

Comment: Why would someone vote down this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you, I would keep a food journal.  It's free and you can record every aspect of your nutritional intake including protein, carbs, fats, calories etc.  All that is required is that you read food labels and/or buy a calorie counter.  Knowing what you're currently consuming will allow you to plan much better than guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Sites like myfitnesspal.com (which I use) have exercise logs which you can use to track amount of calories burned. Maybe you should check one of those out.

Edit:
As mentioned in @rrirower answer, food logging is equally important. Sites like www.noom.com or myfitnesspal.com have both food and exercise logging.

Comment: but how accurate are they?

Comment: I would say accurate enough, but only if they account your weight in the calculation (along with the rest of parameters, like speed and gradient). You can never have it 100% accurate, but for weight loss tracking I would say they are accurate enough.

Comment: related: [Is Strava overestimating my calories burned from walking?](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/25543/is-strava-overestimating-my-calories-burned-from-walking/25548#25548)

Answer (score -1):

For me, what works is using sites like [wikicalories](https://www.wikicalories.com) to know how many calories are there in the food I eat in every meal. Diet in my opinion and calorie counting is more important than going to the gym regularly - at least, this is what works for me. I dont log my food but I check the calories in them before I consume. Good luck with your goals!